# Prevent a function to trigger

Tags: javascript

tl;dr this function is applying a 20% discount by default when the field is empty or has a value of 0, how do I prevent it from triggering from the get go?

```
function longlost() {
  
  var months = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#months').value);
  var finalPrice = (getServicePrice() + extraPrices()) * getDiscountPercent(months);
  document.getElementById("result").value = "€" + finalPrice;
}
```

I've also tried like so but no luck:

```
function longlost() {
  var months = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#months').value);
  if (months.length==0)
   return ;
  var months = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#months').value);
  var finalPrice = (getServicePrice() + extraPrices()) * getDiscountPercent(months);
  document.getElementById("result").value = "€" + finalPrice;
}
```

Comment: `months` is a float since you `parseFloat` the value. A float does not have `.length` it only has a value. You probably meant `months <= 0`. Shouldn't it be parseInt if it is a number of months..? Use `console.log(months)` and you see the value - no luck required.

Comment: @PeterKrebs "No luck required!" 

Comment: @PeterKrebs Doesn't seem to work either way, even when with parseInt. As for the console log (months) is giving me NaN

Comment: Yes but you still continue to check for its `.length`. Numbers don't have that which the console.log lets you know. I'm saying don't guess so much and use debugging tools.

Answer (score 3):

```js
// Check for invalid number or number not being positive
if (isNaN(months) || months <= 0) return;
```

Comment: partially worked, when I enter a value and then replace it to a 0 or alike the rest of the functions stop updating

Comment: @tatoroast What do you want the output to be when it's 0? You haven't specified.

Comment: that was a misunderstanding on my end, whenever the value is 0 or the input field is empty I want for this function alone to not trigger

Comment: @tatoroast So this does accomplish that. Is there another issue?

Comment: in short yes it accomplishes that the problem is that that way none of the other functions update, every one stops unless I refresh the page

Comment: @tatoroast I'm not sure what you mean. You should provide more code and a [mre].

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nytbaju3/

Comment: @tatoroast Could you explain what you mean by the other functions stop? What is the expected behavior? It doesn't look like any of the other functions update the DOM.

Comment: for example here https://jsfiddle.net/d986tg3w/ this is my code without any changes, whatever value I choose from the dropdown menu + each box I check it auto updates the final value at the bottom.
I wanted for the function that calculates the discount to not trigger by default, because even if it's value is 0 it applies a discount of 20%

Comment: @tatoroast Okay, but what's the issue after adding the if statement? If you change the value to 0 do you want the output to be cleared?

Comment: adding the If statement makes it stop updating the value at the bottom. All other functions also stop updating

Comment: @tatoroast So what do you want it to update to when the value is 0?

Comment: to whichever value it was before giving it a value other than 0
as an example: I choose the option 1500€ +tick 1 box of 400€, should give me 1900€. If I place a value of 1 (in my case 1= 5%) the final value would be 95€ , if I place a value of 0 it reverts back to the 1900€

Comment: @tatoroast Just store the previous value in a variable and set it back before the `return` in the check.